# Unauthenticated requests are not allowed. SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, function, api

I am a beginner learner of Js using Nodejs. here is the code bellow like this:

```
const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const request = require('request');

    const app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

    app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    });

    app.post("/", (req, res, next) =>{
    try {
    var crypto = req.body.crypto;
    var fiat = req.body.fiat;
    var baseURL = "https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/all?crypto=crypto&fiat=fiat";
    var finalURL = baseURL + crypto + fiat;

    request(finalURL, (error, response, body) => {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    var price = data.last;
    res.send("<h1>The current price of " + crypto + " is " + price + fiat + "</h1>");
    });

    } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    }
    });
```

but it sends me an error like this and I am not unable to understand it.

undefined:1
    Unauthenticated requests are not allowed. Take out a new plan or start a free trial at https://pro.bitcoinaverage.com
    ^

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Request._callback (F:\ProgProb\WebDep\Bitcoin-Ticker\index.js:38:20)
at Request.self.callback (F:\ProgProb\WebDep\Bitcoin-Ticker\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:311:20)
at Request.<anonymous> (F:\ProgProb\WebDep\Bitcoin-Ticker\node_modules\request\request.js:1154:10)
at Request.emit (events.js:311:20)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (F:\ProgProb\WebDep\Bitcoin-Ticker\node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:28)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:323:22)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Api returns a string:

> Unauthenticated requests are not allowed. Take out a new plan or start a free trial at https://pro.bitcoinaverage.com ^

You are trying to parse this response to JSON so you get an error.

> var data = JSON.parse(body);

You should get a public api key by creating an account (https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/#authentication).

and add header with it like in example:

```
var crypto = require('crypto-js');

var public_key = 'enter your public key';
var ticker_btcusd_url = 'https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTCUSD';

var request = require('request');
var options = {
url: ticker_btcusd_url,
    headers: {
        'x-ba-key': public_key
    }
};
function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Source: https://github.com/bitcoinaverage/api-integration-examples/blob/master/javascript_examples/authentication.js

Answer (score 0):

```
//try to declare baseURL like this:

var baseURL="https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/";
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//this code worked for me:
//--------------------------------------------------------
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/",function(req,res){

try{
  var crypto = req.body.crypto;
  var fiat = req.body.fiat;
  var baseURL = "https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/";
  var finalURL = baseURL + crypto + fiat;


request(finalURL,function(error,response,body){
  var data = JSON.parse(body);
  var price = data.last;
  res.send("<h1>The current price of " + crypto + " is " + price + fiat + "</h1>");
});
}catch(err){
  console.log(err);
}
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log('server is running on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This answer can work out.

```
 const express = require("express");
 const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
 const request = require("request");
 const app = express();

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

 app.listen(3000, function () {
     console.log("server is running at port 3000");
 });

 app.get("/", function (req, res) {
     res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
 });


 app.post("/", function (req, res) {
     
     var theFirstSymbol = req.body.crypto;
     var theSecondSymbol = req.body.fiat;
     var theAmount = req.body.amount;

    var options = {
              url: "https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/convert/global",
              headers : {
             'x-ba-key': 'ZjUzYThkNjY1ZWMzNDYzNmJhZWM2ZGRhZTEyZThmZjU' 
          },
          method: "GET",  //All request are GET requests      
          qs: {
             from: theFirstSymbol,
             to: theSecondSymbol,
             amount: theAmount,
          }
    
     }

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        var data = JSON.parse(body); 
        var price = data.price;
        res.send("<h1> The current price of " +theFirstSymbol + " is " price + "</h1>");
    });

 });
```

1. You should get a public key and the way to use the key is shown above.
2. Require bitcoinaverage and cypto-js as dependencies.
3. And please read the documentation under authentication on the website of bitcoin i.e https://bitcoinaverage.com